# Can "Functions Framework" be used to run/debug Firebase Functions locally?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, functions-framework

Google's "Functions Framework" is designed to run and debug "Google Cloud Functions" locally, [see link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks).

On the other hand, Firebase Functions docs only mention the emulator as a means to run/debug Firebase Functions locally, [see link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator). I have not been able to find any mention online of Firebase Functions working in the Functions Framework.

However, in some ways it would appear that any Firebase Function is actually also at the same time a "Google Cloud Function". For example, whenever you create a new Firebase Function, it will appear in the list of Google Cloud Functions in the [Google Cloud Functions Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions/list).

Given that the Functions Framework is supposed to be a superior debugging solution to emulators, I would like to know if I can use it with Firebase Functions or not.

Any clarification on the difference (or lack thereof) between Firebase Functions and Google Cloud Functions would also be welcome.

Comment: Firebase Functions ARE Cloud Functions so it stands to reason that you should be able to use the 'Functions Framework' assuming your Cloud Function is written in Node.js. At its core the Function Framework creates a local server that you can send requests to, so its doing the same thing the Firebase Function emulator does. Frankly I don't think one is superior to other, its just a matter of convenience. If you're working with Firebase, use the emulator since its tailor made for the Firebase ecosystem. If you're working with a pure Cloud Function then use the Function Framework for testing.

Comment: Thanks. Since posting the question I started trying out the emulator and it works well. Using `connectFunctionsEmulator(cloudFunctions, '127.0.0.1', 5001);` in my app, then `firebase emulators:start --project test --inspect-functions --only functions` on the command line.